# NodeJS - readline pause and resume event emitter (read line by line)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using Node v.0.8.9, and its module `readline`. I cannot use `fs.readFile()` since I get `EISDIR` error.

I would like to read line by line from a file, do some work, and only then (when the work is complete) to read the next line. Thus, I tried the following snippet (see below) but when changing the `for` with some synchronous work, it does not behave synchronously.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var readline = require("readline");
var filename = process.argv[2];

readline.createInterface({
    input: fs.createReadStream(filename),
    terminal: false
}).on("line", function(line){
   this.emit("pause", line);
}).on("pause", function(line) {
    console.log("pause");
    console.log(line);
    console.log("doing some work");
    for (var i = 0; i < 1000000000; ++i);
    this.emit("resume");
}).on("resume", function() {
    console.log("resume");
}).on("close", function() {
    console.log("close");
});
```

Could one shed the light on the issue?

Comment: The error indicates you 're trying to read from a directory.

Comment: @IoannisKaradimas, nope. i verified it already. it happens since the file is too big.

Comment: You should update your question reflecting this to avoid responses similar to my comment. Also, it would be good if you indicated the file's size, in case it's some OS - based limitation or something similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although it is common to read line by line from a file, NodeJS has no implementation for supporting such big files. Hence, you will need to implement it using a buffer.

Here is one which works beautifully - http://blog.jaeckel.com/2010/03/i-tried-to-find-example-on-using-node.html

Comment: I disagree :-) The `readline` module of node has two methods which help a lot when handling big files: `pause` and `resume`. If you don't want to call them yourself you can use something like a buffered-data-sink: https://www.npmjs.com/package/buffered-data-sink . It buffers data and pauses the reader when the queue is full. You only need to set the buffer size and queue limit.

Answer (score 0):

Just a hunch.... try actually calling `pause()` instead of emitting the `pause` event.

That is, change:

```
this.emit("pause", line);
```

to...

```
this.pause();
```

Let me know if this works.

Comment: firstly, i cannot use it since i have to pass an argument. but even if i solve the argument thing, it behaves in the same way.